# Android: Disconnect bluetooth headset to connect my SPP app using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, disconnect

I have a SPP Bluetooth app, the problem is this case.
The android device is connected to a Bluetooth Speaker, when i try to connect to my SPP Micro device i can't for the same reason the Bluetooth is already connected.

How i can disconnect the Bluetooth Speaker from my App so i can connect to my SPP micro device after the disconnection.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Sorry, i forget to specify, the connection to the Bluetooth speaker is made before opening my app, its already connected to the speaker when i open my app and i want to disconnect the bluetooth speaker from my app that didn't connect to the bluetooth speaker and with my app close that connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually disconnect your device by closing the socket

**You need to check, If the devices are connected**. If yes, call reset function

```
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
       resetConnection
    }
```

**ResetConnection** function definition.

```
private void resetConnection() {
    if (mBTInputStream != null) {
            try {mBTInputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            mBTInputStream = null;
    }

    if (mBTOutputStream != null) {
            try {mBTOutputStream.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            mBTOutputStream = null;
    }

    if (mBTSocket != null) {
            try {mBTSocket.close();} catch (Exception e) {}
            mBTSocket = null;
    }

}
```

**Edit 1**
You will have to create a new BluetoothSocket and then call this method `getRemoteDevice()`.

> **getRemoteDevice ()**
>   
> Added in API level 5
>   **Get the remote device this socket is connecting or connected to.**

Here is a link to Documentation [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getRemoteDevice())

Comment: Sorry, i forget to specify, the connection to the Bluetooth speaker is made before opening my app, its already connected to the speaker when i open my app and i want to disconnect the bluetooth speaker from my app that didn't connect to the bluetooth speaker and with my app close that connection

Comment: @user3140190 I edited my answer. Kindly have a look. If your query is resolved, kindly upvote and mark the answer correct.

Comment: Hello M.S.P.
Thanks for your answer, another question, how do get the mBTSocket from the current paired device?

Comment: @williamcabrera4 Once again, I have edited my post. Kindly give it a try

Comment: @Milind Purswani, where is it? I don't see how can we get mBTSocket which is NOT created by app. We cannot just new a BluetoothSocket, it is usually return when we call `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()`/`createRfcommSocketToServiceRecordceRecord()`